# Model fit / Forecast accuracy / Predictors / Explanatory power predictors (panel data)

Tags: forecasting, panel-data, model, r-squared, mse

I have the following data structure: 100 individuals (forecasters) predicted the likelihood of the outcomes of 50 events (binary outcomes, 1 or 0). For each event, each forecaster made two different predictions for the same outcome. The two predictions differ in how the forecasters were asked to compute the likelihood of the outcomes (think of two different reasoning algorithms). So:

| ID | Event | PredicitionA | PredicitionB | Realized Outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | .50 | .58 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | .20 | .20 | 0 |
| 1 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | 50 | .90 | .95 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 100 | 50 | .67 | .70 | 1 |

Predictions within individuals are clearly not independent, and thus these data represent panel data, where ID is the "panel variable" and event is the "time variable".

My goal is to test the performance of the two predictors against each other, so PredictionA vs. PredictionB. Forecasters were incentivized by a quadratic scoring rule.

Now there are my two candidate approaches:

1. I can compute the MSE (and, say, MAD, MAPE) for PredictionA and PredictionB by simply subtracting 1 from the predicted probability if Event 1 occurred and squaring the difference, or squaring the predicted likelihood if Event 1 did not occur. I could then calculate the delta between MSE_PredictionA and MSE_PredictionB and run a fixed effects panel regression against a constant, which is basically a paired t-test of differences.
2. I could also do linear panel regressions by first regressing the realized outcomes (Y) on PredictionA (X), and then redoing the same regression with PredictionB as the predictor (X). I can then compare R^2, the goodness of fit (or r, the correlation coefficient). The higher the R^2, the better the model's predictive power. To obtain p-values to see which model's R^2 is better than the other, I will bootstrap 10,000 replicates.

Which of the two approaches makes more sense conceptually? Are there differences in assumptions? Somehow, the first approach shows me no difference between PredictionA and PredictionB (at least parametrically, non-parametric tests are highly significant, the reason being outliers). However, the second approach shows that PredictionB exceeds the R^2 of PredictionA by 32% with p<.001. This confuses me a bit since R^2 is basically just a standardized and inverted MSE. I couldn't really find the answer on this page.

Thanks for your help! I really appreciate your advice - I am stuck.

Comment: I agree that this result seems confusing at first sight, as both approaches consider similar quantities. The first approach feels simpler and more direct, though.